# Prove that $2+ \dfrac{1}{x^5}$ is uniformly continuous on $[1,\infty)$ with $\epsilon-\delta$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm stuck on finding an $\delta$ for this problem  :

$\left | 2 + \dfrac{1}{x^5} - \left(2+\dfrac{1}{y^5}\right)\right | = \left | \dfrac{1}{x^5} -\dfrac{1}{y^5}\right |$ =  $ \dfrac{\left |x^5 - y^5\right|}{x^5y^5} \leq |x^5-y^5|$

I'm not sure what $\delta$ to pick here to link $|x-y| \leq \delta$ with $|x^5-y^5|$.

I tried $\delta = y \implies x < 2y$ but couldn't get anywhere with this $\delta$.

Comment: *Hint:* $x^5-y^5 = (x-y)(x^4+x^3y+x^2y^2+xy^3+y^4)$.

Comment: Getting rid of $x^5y^5$ in the denominator is not going to work. You have to keep them. Then use Martin’s hint. Showing it for $|x^5-y^5|$ would imply that $g(x)=x^5$ is uniformly continuous, which it is not.

Comment: It would be good to start with a definition of "uniform continuity".  When you go looking for a $\delta$, what property or properties must that $\delta$ satisfy?  What are $x$ and $y$ in your computation?  What is the relation that you are trying to create between them?

Comment: Hint:  The choice of $\delta$ is going to depend on the value given to $\epsilon$, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any $\epsilon > 0$, choose $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{5}$. Then $|x-y|<\delta$ implies:
$$\begin{align}
\left|\left(2+\frac{1}{x^5}\right) - \left(2+\frac{1}{y^5}\right)\right|
&= \left|\frac{1}{x^5} - \frac{1}{y^5}\right| \\
&= \left|\frac{x^5 - y^5}{x^5y^5}\right| \\
&= |x-y|\left|\frac{x^4+x^3 y+x^2 y^2+x y^3+y^4}{x^5y^5}\right| \\
&< \delta \left|\frac{1}{xy^5} + \frac{1}{x^2 y^4} + \frac{1}{x^3y^3} + \frac{1}{x^4y^2} + \frac{1}{x^5 y}\right| \\
&\le 5\delta \\
&= \epsilon
\end{align}$$

Answer (score -1):

If $|f'|\le M$ on $[1,\infty),$ then $|f(y)-f(x)|\le M|y-x|$ for all $x,y\in [1,\infty)$ by the MVT. Such an $f$ is therefore uniformly continuous on $[1,\infty).$

In our problem we have $f'(x) = (-5)x^{-6},$ which implies $|f'|\le 5$ on $[1,\infty)$ and thus $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[1,\infty).$

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question, which asks for an $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ argument.